# PHP - How would I go about defining a method with another method?

Tags: php

Suppose I have this class with these methods...

```
Class Foo {

public function bar {
return 'foo';
}

public function nothing {
//Nothing.
}

}
```

How would I go about defining the nothing method with the bar method, assuming I cannot manipulate anything but the bar method?

I've exhausted my google-fu and haven't found anything useful, but I get the sense that I just don't know the proper terminology to find an appropriate answer. Thanks in advance for the help!

ANSWERED in comments - thank you!

Here's a secondary question...assuming you could manipulate anything *other* than the nothing method, what would be the appropriate way of defining it?

Comment: You cant - why are you trying to do this? In what scenario can you edit one method of a class but not another?

Comment: Wait, what? You want to add a method to the class via code from another method in the same class? That doesn't really make any sense if I'm understanding you correctly. Perhaps tell us what you're hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: Runkit! Fantastic, thank you. I totally understand that this seems like an XY problem, but I sincerely appreciate the answer. I'd mark it as such, but it's just a comment!

Comment: Secondary question...and I know these might seem strange...assuming you could manipulate anything _other_ than the nothing method...is there a more appropriate way of defining the nothing method?

Comment: There's no such thing as "appropriate" here - this isn't a thing *anyone, ever* actually does. I can't imagine what your use case is, I'm a little afraid to know at this point - but however you manage to achieve it is fine to be honest.

Comment: Haha, I understand it seems strange. Thanks for the help - it's appreciated!

Comment: So are you going to explain what you are trying to achieve? There has got to be a better way. Plus i'm intrigued!

Comment: Another developer asked me if there was a way. I thought their might be, and googled my hardest! Nothing more than that, really.

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to steal Paul's thunder here - his answer is correct, and the point about XY problem is *very* pertinent, but...

Runkit is [not a standard part of PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65459) and likely never will be. [Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and the [_call magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) *are*. Between them these should provide provide the ability to achieve most of the outcomes you would use runkit for on PHP code other than builti-ins. The only snag being that you can no longer use $this as a variable name in a functions argument list.